# Regarding to $ \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}\sum_{k=n-1}^{N}C_{kn}$, prove or disprove!

Tags: sequences-and-series

Regarding to 
$$
\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}\sum_{k=n-1}^{N}C_{kn},
$$
prove or disprove:

(a) If $\sum_{k=n-1}^{\infty}C_{kn}$ is **convergent** to $c_n$, for all $n\geq 1$,
and $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n$ is **absolutely convergent**, then the above limit exists and
$$
(*) \;\;\;\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}\sum_{k=n-1}^{N}C_{kn}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=n-1}^{\infty}C_{kn}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n.
$$

(b) If $\sum_{k=n-1}^{\infty}C_{kn}$ is **absloutely convergent** to $c_n$, for all $n\geq 1$,
and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n$ is  **convergent**, then the above limit exists and
$(*)$ holds.

(c) If $\sum_{k=n-1}^{\infty}C_{kn}$ is **absloutely convergent** to $c_n$, for all $n\geq 1$,
and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n$ is **absolutely  convergent**, then $(*)$ holds (and the  iterated series  is absolutely convergent).

(Note that $\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}\sum_{k=n-1}^{N}C_{kn}=\sum_{n=0}^{N}\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}C_{nk}$ and the following is ***false***: if $\sum_{k=n-1}^{\infty}C_{kn}$ is **convergent** to $c_n$ , for all $n\geq 1$, and $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}c_n$ is **convergent**, then 
$\lim_{N\rightarrow \infty}\sum_{n=1}^{N+1}\sum_{k=n-1}^{N}C_{kn}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=n-1}^{\infty}C_{kn}.$)

Comment: Please do not ask homework questions here.

Comment: This is not a homework, it comes from a problem about (analytic) summability of real and complex functions. Many results are dependent on the above statements.

Comment: Nevertheless, this is the wrong site for this type of question, which is for mathematicians engaged in research. Such questions should be asked at Mathematics StackExchange. Migrating it now...